# How to describe "the remaining portion of a target" in a simple term or phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say I run a car dealership and I gave my sales a target of selling 50 cars this month. They have sold 25 already. Is there a word to describe the remaining 25 cars? For example, the goal of selling 50 cars is the target. The 25 cars sold can be called fulfillment or completed.

Comment: For single word requests, you are required to include a sample sentence to demonstrate how the word would be used. This gives people a better idea of the sort of word you're expecting.

Comment: "The remainder" maybe.

Comment: From the perspective of the "sales target", those unsold vehicles (the "remaining" portion of the target) are the ***shortfall*** or ***deficit***.

Answer (score 1):

I can find no single word but such a target is sometimes referred to as a quota

> Quota = fixed limit on the amount of something that someone is allowed to have or is expected to do:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quota)

The remaining part is referred to as the *unfulfilled quota*.

Examples are easy to find online. Here is one chosen at random:

> In May, in its proposal to reform the Dublin asylum system, the commission said member states who do not accept to relocate asylum seekers would have to pay €250,000 per person in their unfulfilled quota.
>
> [euobserver](https://euobserver.com/migration/135151)